# How to mute/unmute and also know the speaker status in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application which has mute/unmute functionality can you please know how can I mute and unmute through programming and also how will I know my speaker status?

Thanks in advance

Comment: mute/unmute functionality ? are you asking about Background Music?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do so.I have done this once.here is the code for this:-

```
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
    musicPlayer.volume = 0;//For mute.
```

you must add MediaPlayer.framework and import it. `#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>`

```
musicPlayer.volume = 1;//for unmute.
```

Hope this will help you out.